# Implementing GetHashCode for string in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I want to create a scalar function in T-SQL that would be analogous to those, say, in Java.

The standard implementation in imperative languages is:

```
int hash = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    hash = 31*hash + value[i];
}
return hash;
```

I'm not really that good in tsql to implement this, and from my POV writing imperative-style code in t-sql is something that should be avoided. I guess this could be done using CTE? Please =)

Also, can I make it always be positivie, i.e. when results exceed integrer max, then it flows over 0 rather than integer min? Let's assume that number of possible arguments (number of that special classes in my solution) is not really large. Let's say it will never exceed 1000, so I'm sure one can avoid collisions here even with uint.

---

**PS:** If someone's interesed what do I need this for, than I can explain, and probably you can suggest a better solution. I have a table with `integer` identity column and a `varchar` column `'TypeFullName'`- thats a full name of a class in our C# solution.

And I need to write a script that will manually set ID's as a function-dependence of `TypeFullName` (yes, turn on the `SET IDENTITY INSERT` option). So that I can compute ID, if I know the type name. I know that sounds like a system with bad design, and it probably is, but believe me, I just have to do this now)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution in the [internet](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic516137-1315-1.aspx#bm645014) and slightly updated it to limit output to positives:

```
begin
declare @h bigint
set @h = 0
select @h = (@h*31 + ascii(substring(@str,X.pos,1)))%4294967296
   from (select top(len(@str)) 
             row_number() over (order by getdate()) as pos 
           from sys.all_objects) as X
if @h >= 2147483647 set @h = @h - 2147483647
return convert(int, @h)
end;
```

That `select top from sys.all_objects` is really hacky, but ((( at least it works.

Comment: That row_number() over is a TALLY Table.  See Jeff Moden for more details.  Basically it is table of numbers to cross against.  Therefore, you are looking at each character and apply the conversion.

Comment: yeah, I know how it works, that will just list values 1..n, so it kinda works as an iterator. What I'm saying is that it looks like a hack )

Comment: The only alternative is to create a table [msdb].[dbo].[Tally] and load it with 1 M rows or the max iterator you might use.  Change code to '(SELECT TOP(LEN(@str)) from [msdb].[dbo].[Tally]) as X'.  Tally tables suppose to be quicker than WHILE loops.  But does look funny since it references sys.all_objects.  (HACK)

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA, thank you for your advices! I will accept my answer, if you don't mind, since that solution is more up to my request, although your variant also makes sense. I wish I could give a second upvote, but... ))

Answer (score 1):

Read my article on CheckSum versus Hashbytes.  (http://craftydba.com/?p=3005)  
They are two built in SQL Server functions that will generate you a hash key given a value.  One is more unique than another.

If you still have questions, just ask.

Sincerely

John

www.craftydba.com

PS:

You are losing precision when casting to a int or big int.  Just save it as a GUID (16 byte hex).

[image]

Comment: Hi! I thought about using MD5, but I need to limit the output to positive integers. =)
It is easier to do with the descibed hashcode algoritm - just do `hash = hash % (2^32)` at each iteration and then `if (hash > 2147483647) { hash-=2147483647; }`. (I guess something like that...)

Comment: And with MD5 hash I can't do anything, what shall I do, for inst, with `convert(int, HashBytes('MD5', 'test1'))`? It gives me -1574543990.

Comment: Addition to first comment: in that case, I'd start with long (bigint in sql-server), and then just cast it to int before return.

Comment: `You are losing precision when casting to a int or big int. Just save it as a GUID (16 byte hex).` 
well, but I need `int`, since my `id` column is `int`,